# How to change a div's height (500px) to auto after a paragraph inside it reaches 500px in height?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want a to have a text box where you can write in, and currently I am using a div with a background and a paragraph (

) inside the div. I want the div to cover the page except for a margin, but then if you go past the limit of 500px, the div's height in the CSS changes to auto so that there is still a background as you go down the page.

The code below is not the full version, I removed what was unnecessary for simplicity's sake.

```css
/* Body Preferneces */

body {
  background-color: #00C5CD;
  font-size: 25px;
}


/* Paragraph Text Preferences */

p {
  font-size: 25pt;
  color: #000;
}

#text {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="text">
    <div id="identifier">
      <p contenteditable="true"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think you're looking for `#text { min-height: 500px; }`

Comment: @Michael Coker Thanks so much, I've been looking for this forever, but it's no where on google. Thanks.

Comment: no problem. if you're going to leave the question open, let me know if you'd like me to submit as an answer.

Comment: @MichaelCoker sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on @MichaelCoker 's comment... `min-height` works well:

```css
/* Body Preferneces */

body {
  background-color: #00C5CD;
  font-size: 25px;
}


/* Paragraph Text Preferences */

p {
  font-size: 25pt;
  color: #000;
}

#text {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="text">
    <div id="identifier">
      <p contenteditable="true"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope it helps